# Convert date into individual numerical columns for year month and day SQL

Tags: sql

I have a date column in the format `YY-MON-DD`, e.g. `25-JUN-05`. Is it possible to isolate this into 3 separate columns for year, month and day? Where month is converted from text to numerical, e.g. Year: `25`, Month: `06`, Day: `05`?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: In SQL-Server use `DATEPART` to extract each Part of the date: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datepart.asp and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx . In MySQL use Date-Functions associated with Month, Week,.. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Wonder *Year: 25*

Answer (score 1):

**MS SQL SERVER**

As [Nebi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6214591/nebi) suggested, you can use `DATEPART` and extract each part and store it into different columns.

```
SELECT DATEPART(DAY,'2008-10-22');       -- Returns DAY part i.e 22
SELECT DATEPART(MONTH,'2008-10-22');     -- Returns MONTH part i.e 10
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR,'2008-10-22');      -- Returns YEAR part i.e 2008
```

Comment: Hi, the issue is that month is represented as text. e,g. 25-JUN-05. I get an error when running what you sent.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below script,if you are using SQL Server.

```
SELECT 'Year: '+CAST(LEFT(YourdateColumn,2) as VARCHAR(2))+', Month: ' +CAST(MONTH('01-'+SUBSTRING(YourdateColumn,4,3)+'-15')as VARCHAR(2))+', Day:'+CAST(RIGHT(YourdateColumn,2)as VARCHAR(2))
 FROM Yourtable
```

**sample output :** 
[image]

Comment: I have about 74 rows of data with different dates in the format yy-MON-dd. Will what you sent automatically do it for each date?

Comment: No issues ,try with the updated script by replacing your actual column name and table name.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify your DBMS.

The following is standard SQL assuming that column **really** is a `DATE` column

```
select extract(year from the_column) as the_year,
       extract(month from the_column) as the_month,
       extract(day from the_column) as the_day
from the_table;
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it!